# How do I load taxonomy terms basing on the current language?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am using the following code.

```
$language =  \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('category', 0, 1);
```

How can I change it so it load the taxonomy terms basing on `$language`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [EntityRepositoryInterface::getTranslationFromContext](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityRepositoryInterface.php/function/EntityRepositoryInterface%3A%3AgetTranslationFromContext/8.4.x):

```
$terms_translated = [];
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
  $terms_translated[$key] = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')
    ->getTranslationFromContext($term, $language);
}
```

BTW, you don't need to provide a language code, because the current content language is the default value for the second parameter in getTranslationFromContext() and in a standard multilanguage site this is equal to the current language.

Comment: Thanks @4k4 for answer. I have updated code. Getting error can you please help with that?

Comment: You need a 4th parameter to load the terms: `loadTree('category', 0, 1, TRUE)`. (don't edit the answer into the question, future readers don't see the original question)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  if ($term->hasTranslation($langcode)) {
    $term = $term->getTranslation($langcode);
  }
  ...
}
```

probably more convenient as you dont have to inject entity.repository